# How to decrpyt & extract data from encrypted removable SD card from another device?

Tags: sd-card, encryption, disk-encryption

My Xperia z5 died for an unknown reason and I had to send it for repair. I had an SD card inside for my pictures and kept it home. After a longer time, Sony sent me a **new phone**. Happy, I put back my Sd card to see that the files were existing but are encrypted, the new phone not having the same setting.

I don't really remember setting the encryption but now its too late.

Now my question, I have several pictures saved on my computer unencrypted who are also on the phone. Is it possible to extract the key by comparision or is android encrypting the whole drive making it impossible to find the key when you have the original file at disposal?

Comment: **In short, no. It's not possible, without having the old device.** Why? Think of someone like your enemy, who wants to copy your data when you're not around. So, he removes your memory card and plugs it in his computer to read your data. Do you think he should be able to extract those data from your encrypted card? NO! That's the sole purpose of encryption. Once encrypted, without the key, it's just junk data inside.

Comment: Thanks you, that's fine there is no critical data on it anyway. But I was wondering how the encryption was working, whether it was encrypting each file with the key meaning that when i have the original file and the encrypted one, I should be able to get back the key or if android what encrypting the whole drive, meaning that when you delete one file, you loose everything.

Comment: Not possible without old device where key is stored (still no accessible without root AFAIK) p.s. that key is also wiped when performing factory reset.

Comment: @Thomas On portable SD cards, disk-encryption is performed, meaning that the entire drive is encrypted, not files individually.